# How do I add new users to PostgreSQL 9.1 on Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, user-accounts, postgresql

I am unable to run `psql` with my normal Mac user account in Terminal session, although I can do it using the `postgres` service account). When I enter the command `psql mydb` and type my password, I get the following message:

```
WARNING: password file "/Users/beh/.pgpass" has group or world access; permissions should be u=rw (0600) or less
```

But I cannot find `.pgpass`.

How do I set up and add users to my PostgreSQL 9.1 database on Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Comment: FYI, PostgreSQL [has been updated to 9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1415/).

Answer (score 1):

The file `.pgpass` starts with a dot and therefore is hidden from view by default in most file managers, but you should be able to access it through Terminal.  You probably don't need the `.pgpass` file, so it may be a good idea to delete it.  If you do decide to keep it, edit the password file according to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html) and run `chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass` to fix the permissions.

PostgreSQL user accounts are independent of the operating system, but remember that unless specified on the command line, `psql` will use the current user's system username as both the database name and PostgreSQL username; an error will occur if a database or user by this name does not exist on the database cluster.  To add users, run `psql` as the `postgres` user, then use the [`CREATE ROLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createrole.html) or `CREATE USER` SQL commands.  Unless  the users will connect to the same database, you may want to create databases for each user to avoid errors.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think my Mac is corrupted. Even after creating role, it will not allow me to login. I uninstall POSTGRESQL thinking it will get rid of user POSTGRES from MAC and I can start all over again. But when I try to create POSTGRES in system preferences accounts maintenance,it says user is already there even though I cannot see the user. I am using the Mac administrator account. What can I do to correct problem?

Comment: Delete the `postgres` user using the [`userdel`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel) (or equivalent, if not available on your system) command on the Terminal, then delete the database cluster (stored in `/usr/local/var/postgres` by default) and reinstall PostgreSQL (which will automatically recreate the `postgres` account). If the database cluster is not automatically recreated, do so in the same location where it was deleted using the [initdb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-initdb.html) command.

Comment: @Cheng: Click on the check below the up/down voting controls to accept this as the best answer, so that the community can see that the problem is solved.